# remplazar una tabla en power BI por otra, la dificultad es que la ya existente tiene varias medidas dax, se puede cambiar sin afectar las medidas?

Tags: sql, dax

Saludos se puede remplazar una tabla en power BI por otra, la dificultad es que la ya existente tiene varias medidas dax, se puede cambiar sin afectar las medidas?

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que lo que vos querés hacer es reemplazar la fuente de datos con una nueva tabla: [How to replace Data Source for existing report?](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/How-to-replace-Data-Source-for-existing-report/td-p/58947)

En el caso de que lo que quieras es cambiar una tabla, por otra con nombres diferentes deberías actualizar tus funciones.

Imagino lo más recomendable en tu caso es reemplazar la tabla antigua por la nueva.